# YandexMaps android проблема запуска активити

Tags: android, activity, yandexmapkit

Не знаю, в чем именно проблема, но появилась именно на интеграции в приложения yandex mapkit

запускаю активити с yandex mapkit'ом, и получаю абсолютно пустую (чёрный фон). Повставлял логов после каждой строчки, ни один не выводится, т.е. можно судить, что код не выполняется. Код следующий:

Вызов:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Код акивити:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.i("after onCreate", "ok");
        setContentView(R.layout.yandex_map);
        Log.i("after setContentView", "ok");

        final MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        Log.i("map_view", mapView.toString());
        Log.i("map_view_api", mapView.getApiKey());
        mapView.getSurfaceView();

        MapController mapController = mapView.getMapController();
        mapController.setPositionAnimationTo(new GeoPoint(43, 77));

        mapController.setZoomCurrent(17);
        Log.i("map_controller", mapController.toString());
    }
}
```

АПИ ключ дали, проверял несколько раз, он в порядке. Никаких ошибок не получаю, то есть с точки зрения java машины всё работает прекрасно. Подскажите, куда копать, чтобы найти решение?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, заимплементил, не тот `onCreate`.